Hindi movie that may be made in the 1960's to 1980's
Hi remember this hindi movie vaguely. 
Its about a husband (works with airline at ticketing counter or air traffic control), wife and child who are planning to visit a couple (perhaps friends or in-laws)in another city. Unfortunately they are able to secure only one plane ticket which they use to send their young son (perhaps 8-10 years old) by himself. They secure an air stewardess to take him though into the plane and to ensure that she hands the son over to the couple. They pack food, clothes and money in the small luggage and send him off. 
Through some misfortunate events the kid gets lost in the arriving airport and is found by a thief who takes his bag with the money and address away. Not having information, money or food the child begs on the street, eventually being spotted by the husband of the couple who he was suppose to met. Not recognizing but feeling sorry for him, the husband brings the child home so he can work as a servant. The child is clumsy and breaks things for which the wife gets very angry and slaps him.. he is eventually thrown out. Meanwhile the parents find out their son is missing and go looking for him. At the end they find him injured and mal-noushished at a hospital. 

Please mention a shorter time frame :)

I believe it is during the late 1970s to 1985... it is a color movie.. can't remember the actors

Did you recognize the city name, any locations? When and where did you watched this movie? Any songs if you remembered in case?
